# Endpoint given by Okteto can't be reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose, okteto

I'm new to app deployment. I wanted to deploy this AI model from [MAX-Image-Caption-Generator](https://github.com/IBM/MAX-Image-Caption-Generator). For deploying the model, I use Okteto and this is what I've done:

1. Create `docker-compose.yml` like this:

   ```
   version: "3.9"
   services:
     max-image-caption-generator:
       image: quay.io/codait/max-image-caption-generator
       ports:
          - 5000
   ```
2. `okteto stack deploy`. Which give me these results:
   [image]
   [image]
3. I tried to open the given endpoint but it can't be reached. This is the memory usage because I wonder if it was the cause I couldn't reach the endpoint
   [image]

Anything I can do to make sure that the model is successfully deployed so I could see result like this on my endpoint?[image]

Answer (score 1):

When running services inside a container, make sure that the server is running on the `0.0.0.0` interface so that it can listen to requests coming from the external network.

[This post](https://community.okteto.com/t/service-is-running-but-not-listening-error/57/4) in the Okteto community site has more information on this.